# How to stretch resolution in WebGL platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution, unity-webgl

I am working on home design project for WebGL platform.

But it doesn't fit to the window while I am changing the browser window size.

How can I fit it to browser window?

Comment: Let me see if I'm understanding. You'd like to create a WebGL that is responsive to your webpage. Is that right?

Comment: I am working on unity project and my client want WebGL verision.
and I want the screen size fit to the browser window size.

Comment: The only solution I can think is: You'll have to create a game that resizes with the screen. Using unity's canvas system should do the trick. After that, you'll need to resize the WebGL to fit the screen like any other element on your website. Take a look at this: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html

Comment: Also, this guy had a similar problem before: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1336800/scale-unity-webgl-canvas-to-fit-browser-window.html